# Directory to Variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have this directory structure, and would only like to take the 7rd level as a variable

```
D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3\A\A_Day_To_Remember\Album1
D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3\A\Abroo\Album1
D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3\A\Abroo\Album2
D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3\A\ACDC\Album1

D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3\B\Beatsteaks\Album1
D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3\B\Bee_Gees\Album1
D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3\B\Bell_Book_and_Candle\Album1
etc..
```

I would now like to take the artist name into a variable.

example ACDC, Beatsteaks, Abroo etc

```
import os
main_path = r'D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3'


def main():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main_path):
        for dir in dirs:
            print(dirs)






['A', 'B']
['A', 'B']
['Abroo', 'ACDC', 'A_Day_To_Remember']
['Abroo', 'ACDC', 'A_Day_To_Remember']
['Abroo', 'ACDC', 'A_Day_To_Remember']
['Album1']
['Album2']
['Album1']
etc...
```

but so here everything is output, how can I narrow it down to the artist?

Comment: make a counter, increase on each loop. when desired depth reached do something different - f.e. add to a list? What is your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to tackle the problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import os
main_path = r'D:\home\user\arc\music\MP3'

def main():
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(main_path):
    depth = 0
    for dir in dirs:
        depth = depth + 1
        if depth == 1:
          print(dir)

main()
```

please adjust 1 in `if depth == 1` to appropriate value